# Running firefox in a ubuntu docker container on localhost: Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported:

Tags: docker, ubuntu, x11

I am experimenting with running X11 GUI programs from a docker container on localhost:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox
ARG home=/root
WORKDIR $home
COPY entrypoint.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

where the `entrypont.sh` file is:

```
#! /bin/bash
firefox &
exec bash
```

Building the image with:

```
docker build -t firefox-ubuntu-2004 .
```

And running the container (localhost: Ubuntu 20.04):

```
XSOCK=/tmp/.X11-unix
XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth
DISPLAY="localhost:0"
xauth nlist $DISPLAY | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -
docker run -it --rm \
       -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
       -v $XAUTH:$XAUTH \
       -v $XSOCK:$XSOCK \
       -e XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH \
       firefox-ubuntu-2004
```

The output error message from running the last command is:

```
Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: localhost:0
Error: cannot open display: localhost:0
```

Comment: Even I am seeing same error. My setup is..... I am connected to Ubuntu 18 and trying to open Firefox using xQuartx in Mac. when opening Firefox in ubuntu18 terminal, I am seeing same error.

Answer (score 1):

The `--net=host` in the docker command should do the job

```
docker run --name myContainer -it --net=host  fromMyimage:latest
```

along with using `host.docker.internal` instead of localhost for connecting to the docker's host on  OSX.